# Is it possible to block countries IP using the security group on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

Is it possible to block an entire country from access my website within a security group rule in an Amazon EC2 instance instead of using iptables or something else?

Comment: Even if it were, it's trivial for people to circumvent that block with proxy servers. That is very commonly done, especially by the kinds of people you usually would want to block.

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah but it's good for block some spam/crawlers bot unwanted...or not?

Comment: They are probably used to getting IP blocked and already use proxies. If EC2 can do that, it can't *hurt* (as long as you don't expect legitimate users from those countries), but I doubt it will help much either.

Comment: Recommend to read the document on how to set `Network ACL in AWS` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html . it is not perfect solution, but you can use that as a start.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the others commented, it is hard to block the traffic from particular countries, if someone is smart enough to use a proxy.

But you can use some simple ways to filter most traffic from a range of IPs (not all customers know to use proxy)

One is to set `Network ACL` in aws. Please go though aws document [Network ACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) as a start.

Another way if you can manage route 53 for your website, enable `geolocation route policy` and transfer the traffic from some countries to a fake website. You can go through the document here [Choosing a Routing Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html)

Comment: I don't see a way in Network ACL to use geolocation.

Comment: it's on route53 service not on network acl

Comment: public IP addresses have physical location. You need discover by yourself.